# Moving caret in JTextField using PlainDocument

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

I'm writing a custom control, based on JTextField. My JTextField uses my own Document class, derived from PlainDocument, so that I can process all the user input in overriden `insertString(...)` and `remove(...)` methods.

Here's the problem. After I process user input, sometimes I want to move the caret to another position. What is the better way to do it?

By default Document puts the caret next to last input. So I tried to put a char to my target position and delete it immediately. For some reason it doesn't work in `remove()` method... and the code doesn't look nice :)

Thanks for and proposals.

Comment: When you say "overloaded", do you mean that you have extended PlainDocument? When you say you have overloaded the method insertString() and remove(), is it "overloaded"? or "overriden"? Overloaded=same method name but different arguments. Overriden, means you have extended a class and you have rewritten a method existing in the parent class (same name and same arguments)?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean my class is derived from PlainDocument and those methods are overriden.

Comment: _I'm writing a custom control, based on JTextField_ - why? What functionality should it have that core doesn't support? Remember: all JSomething are designed to be used as-are, simply configure to suite your needs.

Answer (score 2):

- It seems unnecessary to extend PlainDocument. Simply add a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to the Document of your JTextField and you can process the user input in the 3 methods declared in DocumentListener
- Use [setCaretPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29) to move the caret to wherever you would like

Comment: I want to catch user's input and change it before the text field is updated. To be specific - I'm writing a date input control. If user enters inappropriate symbol, document must ignore it, if user pastes a string from clipboard, document must parse it char by char and decide what will go into the field.

Can I do it with DocumentListener? I may be wrong, but looks like it only gives me notification about the input.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov re-inventing the wheel :-) Have a look at JFormattedTextField, it can be configured to do exactly that.

Comment: @kleopatra JFormattedTextField is a good point, thanks! But my customer really wants a brand-new weel :) I don't need to validate already input on focusLost, instead I need to control every users move and alter the input on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You should actually be using a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) if you want to control user input. A `DocumentFilter` allows you to intercept all the input as it happens. You can then use [`JTextField.setCaretPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29) (comes from `JTextComponent`) to set the caret position. Just pass your `DocumentFilter` implementation a reference to the `JTextField` so it can set the caret position for you.

Here's the [Java trail for `DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). Also, an [example on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345628/GUI/java/DocumentFilter).

Comment: if it comes to custom caret positioning, the filter to use is a NavigationFilter. An example of combining both Document-/NavigationFilter is Default/International/Formatter (don't nail me on the exact details, don't have the sources handy at the moment :-)